# Elasticsearch js Bulk Index TypeError

Tags: json, node.js, elasticsearch, bulk-load

### Background

Recently, I have been working with the [Elasticsearch Node.js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) API to bulk-index a large JSON file. I have successfully parsed the JSON file. Now, I should be able to pass the index-ready array into the Elasticsearch bulk command. However, using console log, it appears as though the array shouldn't be causing any problems.

### Bugged Code

The following code is supposed to take an API URL (with a JSON response) and parse it using the Node.js HTTP library. Then using the [Elasticsearch Node.js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) API, it *should* bulk-index every entry in the JSON array into my Elasticsearch index.

```
var APIUrl = /* The url to the JSON file on the API providers server. */
var bulk = [];

/*
  Used to ready JSON file for indexing
*/
var makebulk = function(ParsedJSONFile, callback) {
    var JSONArray = path.to.array; /* The array was nested... */
    var action = { index: { _index: 'my_index', _type: 'my_type' } };

    for(const item of items) {
        var doc = { "id": `${item.id}`, "name": `${item.name}` };

        bulk.push(action, doc);
    }
    callback(bulk);
}

/*
  Used to index the output of the makebulk function
*/
var indexall = function(madebulk, callback) {
    client.bulk({
        maxRetries: 5,
        index: "my_index",
        type: "my_type",
        body: makebulk
    }, function(err, resp) {
        if (err) {
           console.log(err);
        } else {
           callback(resp.items);
        }
    });
}

/* 
   Gets the specified URL, parses the JSON object, 
   extracts the needed data and indexes into the 
   specified Elasticsearch index
*/
http.get(APIUrl, function(res) {
   var body = '';

   res.on('data', function(chunk) {
       body += chunk;
   });

   res.on('end', function() {
       var APIURLResponse = JSON.parse(body);

       makebulk(APIURLResponse, function(resp) {
           console.log("Bulk content prepared");

           indexall(resp, function(res) {
              console.log(res);
           });
           console.log("Response: ", resp);
      });
   });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("Got an error: ", err);
});
```

When I run `node bulk_index.js` on my web server, I receive the following error: `TypeError: Bulk body should either be an Array of commands/string, or a String`. However, this doesn't make any sense because the `console.log(res)` command (From the `indexall` function under `http.get` client request) outputs the following:

```
Bulk content prepared
Response:  [ { index: { _index: 'my_index', _type: 'my_type', _id: '1' } },
  { id: '5', name: 'The Name' }, ... },
  ... 120690 more items ]
```

The above console output appears to show the array in the correct format.

### Question

What does `TypeError: Bulk body should either be an Array of commands/string, or a String` indicate is wrong with the array I am passing into the `client.bulk` function?

### Notes

My server is currently running Elasticsearch `6.2.4` and Java Development Kit version `10.0.1`. Everything works as far as the Elaticsearch server and even my Elaticsearch mappings (I didn't provide the `client.indices.putMapping` code, however I can if it is needed). I have spent multiple hours reading over every scrap of documentation I could find regarding this TypeError. I couldn't find much in regards to the error being thrown, so I am not sure where else to look for information regarding this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems a typo in your code.

```
var indexall = function(**madebulk**, callback) {
    client.bulk({
        maxRetries: 5,
        index: "my_index",
        type: "my_type",
        body: **makebulk**
```

Check the madebulk & makebulk.